# How to address RdKafka::ERR__TIMED_OUT and RdKafka::ERR__MSG_TIMED_OUT in librdkafka?

Tags: c++, apache-kafka

I am working on C++ kafka client **librdkafka**. Looking into the example https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/src-cpp/rdkafkacpp.h and https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.cpp, it seems that there is no process of connecting to broker? How to do some reconnect staff for these connection errors? How to check the connection status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

librdkafka abstracts all broker connectivity from the application, it will attempt to always keep a connection to each known broker (either learnt through `metadata.broker.list` or by the broker list returned from the first bootstrap brokers).

Upon connection error librdkafka will attempt to connect again, forever.

If none of brokers can be connected to the `ALL_BROKERS_DOWN` event will be triggered but there is currently no corresponding event for when brokers being to come back online.
The application doesn't need to worry though since librdkafka takes care of all reconnects and message retransmissions in the background and it will keep trying to get the messages produced until either `message.timeout.ms` or `message.send.max.retries` are exceeded.

There's more information on this in the introduction guide:
https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/INTRODUCTION.md